# Communication between gSOAP client and Java webservice over HTTPS

Tags: java, https, gsoap

I'm developing a client server pair, where the server is based on Java, and the client is based on C++ (gSOAP). The communication works perfectly with using HTTP. Now I want to implement an encrypted communication based on HTTPS.

Therefore I followed the gSOAP tutorial on

https://www.genivia.com/tutorials.html#cert

To create self signed certificates: one for the client, one for the webservice.

Then I converted the .pem files using OpenSSL as you find here:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in Servicecert.pem -inkey Servicekey.pem -certfile cacert.pem -out Service -name "service"
```

Additionally I exported the x.509 Client certificate like this:

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in Clientcert.pem -out Clientcert.der
keytool -import -alias client -keystore Client -file Clientcert.der
```

These two files I'm using as keystore (Service) and truststore (Client)

Now using gSOAP sample code on the client side like this:

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   struct soap* soap = soap_new();
soap->fsslverify = ssl_verify;
   soap_register_plugin(soap, soap_wsse);

   CountriesPortSoap11Proxy service("https://localhost:9443/ws");// = new              CountriesPortSoap11Proxy("https://localhost:9443/ws");

    _ns1__getCountryRequest* request = new _ns1__getCountryRequest;
    _ns1__getCountryResponse response;

    soap_ssl_init();

    if (soap_ssl_client_context(soap,
       SOAP_SSL_ALLOW_EXPIRED_CERTIFICATE, // requires server authentication
      "Client.pem",// keyfile for client authentication to server
      "password",             // the keyfile password
      "cacert.pem",// cafile CA certificates to authenticate the server
      NULL,// capath CA directory path to certificates
      NULL))
    {
       cout << "Zertifikat" << endl;
       soap_print_fault(soap, stderr);
       exit(1); 
    }

    request->name = "Poland";
    request->soap = soap;

  if (soap_ssl_accept((struct soap*)soap))
 cout << "ok" << endl;
    else
 cout << "fail" << endl;; 



    if(service.getCountry(request, response)==SOAP_OK)
    cout << "ok" << endl;
    else{
          cout << "fail" << endl;
    service.soap_stream_fault(std::cerr);
    }   
 cout << response.country->currency << endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

Then I get the following error code

```
ok
fail
SOAP 1.1 fault SOAP-ENV:Server[no subcode]
"SSL_ERROR_SSL
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
unable to get local issuer certificate"
Detail: SSL_connect() error in tcp_connect()
segmentation fault (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

Does someone know what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you had to convert the PEM files as you described. The `cert.sh` script generates the PEM key file and PEM certificate file. This script can be used for server side to generate `server.pem` and `cacert.pem`. The `cert.sh` script is located in `gsoap/samples/ssl` in the gSOAP software package. The `cacert.pem` file is the server's certificate, signed by the root (`root.pem` created with the `root.sh` script). This `cacert.pem` file is the only file needed at the client side to verify the authenticity of the server using the self-signed certificate. Use the `server.pem` file at the server side. The `client.pem` is not needed, unless you enforce client authentication at the server side explicitly with `SOAP_SSL_REQUIRE_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION` to initialize the SSL context with `soap_ssl_server_context`. The `server.pem` file is actually a concatenation of the server's private key and its certificate, when created by `cert.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to convert the PEM files to use them in the java webservice which uses the keytool. This keytool only understands PKCS12 certificates as far as I know. Additionally I had to use the Client certificates, because the Server uses the Client x.509 certificate in a truststore.