# gSOAP HTTPS connection to java webservice

Tags: java, https, gsoap

As you can see in [Communication between gSOAP client and Java webservice over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948525/communication-between-gsoap-client-and-java-webservice-over-https/53350915#53350915)
I tried to get an connection over HTTPS to a Java webservice.

After some research, I figured out that there is a problem with the certificate on the server side.

With the following command I was able to get a connection:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:9443 -CAfile /home/pall/Schreibtisch/DokuSpring/Certificate/CA/cacert.pem -cert /home/pall/Schreibtisch/DokuSpring/Certificate/CA/client.pem -key /home/pall/Schreibtisch/DokuSpring/Certificate/CA/clientkey.pem
```

Does someone know how to convert this three certificates/keys to the

```
soap_ssl_client_context(...)
```

command of gSOAP?

Comment: Why are you using a client key and certificate to connect to a server? Normally a server does not require clients to authenticate to it. Only the -CAfile should be needed, i.e. the cacert.pem which is also passed to `soap_ssl_client_context`.

Comment: I'm using the client key, because I want the client to authenticate against the server. As you can see in the link above, the server has a keystore and a truststore. The latter is for the client authentication

Comment: I tried to remove the truststore on the server side, but I get always the same error message: "SSL_ERROR_SSL
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
unable to get local issuer certificate"